# persistent error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c, pointers, struct, declaration

I'm having problems with my college assignment and I would love some help.

The part of the code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXSTRING 100

int counter = 0;
int maxcounter = 0;
int maxid = 0;

typedef struct{
   char name[MAXSTRING];
   int id;
}student;


 int AddStudent(student st, student *stArray) {
     student t[] = {"",0};
     int id;
     char name[MAXSTRING];

     printf("First enter the student's id\n");
     scanf("%d", &id);
     printf("Now enter the student's name\n");
     scanf("%s", name[MAXSTRING]);

     if (st[maxcounter].id > maxid){
         maxid = t[maxcounter].id;
     }
     maxcounter++;
     t[maxcounter].id = id;
     t[maxcounter].name = name;
    printf("%d", t[maxcounter].id);
      }
```

In every instance of `t[maxcounter]` the following error appears:

```
 error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
         maxid = st[maxcounter].id;
                   ^
```

Do you know what's causing this? Have I not declared the struct right?

Comment: The error says `st`, not `t`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
  scanf("%s", name[MAXSTRING]);
```

is wrong, it should be

```
scanf("%99s", name);
```

That said, seeing the usage in the line

```
if (st[maxcounter].id > maxid){
```

is wrong, as `st` is defined as `student st`. `st` is not an array type, so you cannot use indexing on it, or in other words, you cannot use `st` as the operand of `[]` operator.

Answer (score 0):

`st` is an argument to your function, it is a single value of type `student`. As such, you can't subscript it as the error says. `t` on the other hand is an array of `student`.

Looking at your code, where you have

```
st[maxcounter].id > maxid
```

you probably meant

```
t[maxcounter].id > maxid
```